# Is there a way to load more than 255 columns to a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to load site catalyst data which has close to a 1000 records.  Below shown is the code I'm using:

```
    from pyspark.sql.types import *
    from pyspark.sql import Row
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
    omni_rdd = sc.textFile('hdfs://user/temp/sitecatalyst20170101.gz')
    omni_rdd_delim = omni_rdd.map(lambda line: line.split("\t"))
    omni_df = omni_rdd_delim.map(lambda line: Row(
      col_1 =   line[0]
    , col_2 =   line[1]
    , col_3 =   line[2]
    , ..
    , ..
    , col_999 = line[998]
    )).toDF()
```

I'm coming across the below error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 2
  SyntaxError: more than 255 arguments
```

Is there any way I can load all 1000 columns into my dataframe?

-V

Answer (score 3):

you can do it in this way.
define a list with column names

```
cols = ['col_0' ,'col_1' ,'col_2' ,.........., 'col_999']
```

Use it while creating your dataFrame

```
omni_rdd = sc.textFile('hdfs://user/temp/sitecatalyst20170101.gz')
omni_rdd_delim = omni_rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(","))
omni_df = omni_rdd_delim.toDF(cols)
```

Comment: This leads to the following error:   **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 64, in toDF
    return sqlContext.createDataFrame(self, schema, sampleRatio)
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 423, in createDataFrame
    rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data, schema, samplingRatio)
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 315, in _createFromRDD
    struct.fields[i].name = name
IndexError: list index out of range**
  Any idea how we can rectify this??